# dynamically determine DateTime parsing regex pattern

Tags: c#, datetime

Is it possible to get the DateTime format from DateTime class itself for parsing? We have disparate systems  that return datetime in various formats, how to parse them without knowing the exact regex pattern?

Comment: How do you know it uses Regex in the first place?

Comment: More or less impossible to do it correctly (as there is no way to distinguish mm/dd/yyyy from dd/mm/yyyy), but there are plenty suggestions on SO (one linked as duplicate, more can be found https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+parse+date+unknown+format)

Comment: The `DateTime` struct doesn't have an internal `DateTime` "format". I don't know what you're asking with that. Are you saying that you have a bunch of date/time formatted strings and you'd like to try parse them using a series of possible formats?

Comment: Just because [DateTimeParse.cs](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Globalization/DateTimeParse@cs/4/DateTimeParse@cs)

Comment: @Enigmativity i hoping there is a way to find the format specifier to exactly parse datetime string in a raw text file using DateTime.ParseExact.

Comment: @Syler - Ok so... do you already have the formats ready to place into `Datetime.TryParse` or are they unknown to you and you just have a mixed bag. Because you _need_ to know the formats when using that function. Using the alternative `DateTime.Parse` will only work on known, common formats. So if some of the formats you're looking to convert are custom built, you need to generate the formatting as neither `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` will know that they're indeed valid `DateTime` strings. You have no choice unless you feel like building a custom format parser for your raw data.

Comment: @Syler - Also, don't ask how to do it as there will be a few ways, regex and recursion to name two.

Comment: @Gabe Thats the problem, these log files are being generated by a system and the viewer will showing these raw text files, the problem comes when i need to merge log files from multiple systems and show them in chronological order by date. I can use the TryParse method and pass DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo to prevent using local formatting. I suppose for those few dates that are not valid, the format specifier would have to be specified.

Comment: @Syler - It doesn't make sense to me. If you're getting the raw text from files written by other systems how does it help you to know what the date time format is for the system you're working with? Don't you need to know it from the other systems?

Comment: @enigmativity yes im thinking its best if the other system expose the format specifier in someway like a wcf method call for non standard dates. I think i have the answer now, the format specifier must be exposed for non standard dates.

Comment: @Syler - Another option is that you specify ISO date format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 0):

Use `TryParse` and try various formats, starting from the the most popular one. When `DateTime` is correctly built, `TryParse` returns true and you can use this `DateTime`. Else, try another pattern.

For example:

```
internal DateTime ParseDateString(string dateString)
{
    DateTime myDateTime;
    var attempt1 = doSomeRegex(dateString);
    if (DateTime.TryParse(attempt1, out myDateTime))
    {
        return myDateTime;
    }
    var attempt2 = anotherRegex(dateString);
    if (DateTime.TryParse(attempt2, out myDateTime))
    {
        return myDateTime;
    }
    var attempt3 = lastChanceRegex(dateString);
    if (DateTime.TryParse(attempt3, out myDateTime))
    {
        return myDateTime;
    }
    throw new ArgumentException($"Error parsing date string: {dateString}", nameof(dateString));
}
```

Comment: guessing regex is not a smart way of doing this.

Comment: So what is `01022015`? January 2nd 2015? Or is it February 1st 2015??

Comment: @Syler needs to figure it out between his program and the library that provides these strings.

Comment: ya its so convoluted when it is not supposed to be. @mason you are right, its not possible to parse without knowing the format specifier esp in the case of non standard dates. But i think i have found my answer. for unknown dates format specifier needs to be provided for standard dates tryparse works just fine.